# MySQL - Joining table on itself based on criteria from other table

Tags: mysql, join

Here’s the problem I am trying to solve:

**Table1** has Product ID’s, dates, and prices for those dates, **Table2** has Product attributes.

I want to be able to compare prices for a client for different products on the same date based on a set of attributes. I’m easily able to get a list of products/dates/prices for a ‘simple’ product, as well as an ‘advanced’ product (see below).

I want to be able to join these two tables such that the output looks like:

> [CLIENT] [PRODUCT] [DATE] [SIM_PROD] [SIM_PRICE] [ADV_PROD] [ADV_PRICE]

Here is as far as I've made it

```
SELECT b.NAME AS ‘CLIENT’, a.NAME AS ‘SIMPLE_PRODUCT’, t1.DATE AS ‘DATE’, t1.PIVOT_PRICE AS ‘SIMPLE_PRICE’
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT a
ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = a_PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN CLIENTS b
ON a.PARTNER_ID = b.PARTNER_ID
WHERE a.CRITERIA = TRUE;


SELECT b.NAME AS ‘CLIENT’, a.NAME AS ‘ADV_PRODUCT’, t2.DATE AS ‘DATE’, t2.PIVOT_PRICE AS ‘ADV_PRICE’
FROM TABLE1 t2
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT a
ON t2.PRODUCT_ID = a_PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN CLIENTS b
ON a.PARTNER_ID = b.PARTNER_ID
WHERE a.CRITERIA = FALSE;
```

I've been able to build similar tables where I pull in price from TABLE1 labeling it as t1 then pull in price again from TABLE1 and labeling it as t2, but only when using criteria in TABLE1, not criteria in a table that needs to be joined.

Is it possible to 'set' a table (EG simple) then 'set' a second one (EG advanced) and then join them on PARTNER_ID and DATE?

Comment: If those two queries were two diferent tables which would be field or fields you use to relate one table to the other? In othe words on which criteria do you form the new record you want as output.

Comment: For each combination of Client, Product, and Date how many records you have with the same value of Criteria?  I suggest you provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in MySQL. Column names should be quoted with backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.client, t1.date, t1.simple_product, t1.simple_price, t2.adv_product, t2.adv_price
FROM (
    SELECT b.NAME AS CLIENT, a.NAME AS SIMPLE_PRODUCT, t1.DATE, t1.PIVOT_PRICE AS SIMPLE_PRICE
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT a
    ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = a_PRODUCT_ID
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTS b
    ON a.PARTNER_ID = b.PARTNER_ID
    WHERE a.CRITERIA = TRUE
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT b.NAME AS CLIENT, a.NAME AS SIMPLE_PRODUCT, t1.DATE, t1.PIVOT_PRICE AS SIMPLE_PRICE
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT a
    ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = a_PRODUCT_ID
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTS b
    ON a.PARTNER_ID = b.PARTNER_ID
    WHERE a.CRITERIA = FALSE
) AS t2
ON t1.client = t2.client AND t1.date = t2.date
```

You'll probably need to select additional criteria and add them to the `ON` condition. Otherwise this will produce a full cross product between all the products that have the same client and date.

Your desired output has an additional `PRODUCT` column, but I couldn't see where that comes from.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for - thanks so much!